# Create custom router service

Tags: symfony

am creating own framework based on Sf2 commponents and i try to create router service.

I i need that service for `generateUrl()` method

```
protected function generateUrl($route, $parameters = array(), $referenceType = UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_PATH)
{
    return $this->get('router')->generate($route, $parameters, $referenceType);
}
```

**I try this**

```
$container = new ContainerBuilder();

$container->setDefinition('router_loader', new Definition('Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface'));
$container->setDefinition('router', new Definition('Symfony\Component\Routing\Router', array()));
```

And when i execute in my methodAction

```
$this->generateUrl('home');
```

**he return me:**

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\Routing\Router::__construct() must be an instance of
>   Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface, none given in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\my_fw\vendor\symfony\routing\Router.php on line 95

looking on router constructor i see. I need that interface

```
   public function __construct(LoaderInterface $loader, $resource, array $options = array(), RequestContext $context = null, LoggerInterface $logger = null)
```

how to avoid that implementation in service?

```
**New update:** routing.php

use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

// Routing
$routes = new RouteCollection();

// Home

$routes->add('home', new Route('/', array(
    '_controller' => 'MyCompany\\Controller\\HomeController::indexAction',
)));
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the Router class is an all in one manager type class with very specific requirements: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html#the-all-in-one-router.  If you don't want or need this complexity then just use the UrlGenerator class directly: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html#the-all-in-one-router

Answer (score 0):

You are having this error because you are configuring the router service with no service definition the service definition should have your service arguments which is the source of your error because the container try to create the router with no arguments [check this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/definitions.html)

For better use you can configure the router service in the service.yml/.xml file

Comment: Link just describe how to check if some service is registred or not. And few helper methods. I dont see how to inject interface like argument

Comment: it describe also set arguments http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/definitions.html#constructor-arguments

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: The [documentation page for the Routing component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html#usage) has detailed setup instructions**

Try injecting the `router_loader` service as an argument into the `router` service. For this case you have to use the `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference` class.

Routes have to be configured with a config file when using the all in one `Router` class. You have to use a `FileLocator` and a real Loader class, like the `YamlFileLoader`, you can't just use the interface (services generally can't be interfaces in Symfony).

The service container setup for the `router` service should look like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

// Loads config files from the current directory, change this to 
// your liking, or add more than one path
$container->setDefinition('router_config_locator', new Definition(
    'Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator', [[__DIR__]]
));

$container->setDefinition('router_loader', new Definition(
    'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader', [
        new Reference('router_config_locator'),
    ]
));

$container->setDefinition('router', 
     new Definition('Symfony\Component\Routing\Router', array(
         'loader' => new Reference('router_loader'),
         // Definition of routes in Yaml form
         'resource' => 'routes.yml',
     ))
);
```

The `routes.yml` file contains your route definitions:

```
home:
  path: /home
  defaults: {_controller: "MyController:index"}
```

Also have a look at this documentation page about [setting up the routing component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html#the-all-in-one-router), which also talks about setting up the routing without the all in one class and config file.

Comment: hm this sound good, but i dont use config component. Am using one file `routing.php` where i put collections. Check my update! Can i optimise this without `.yml` and use default `.php`

Comment: @Zend If you want to use the all in one Router class, you have to use the config component. If you just want to use .php files have a look at the [Routing Component Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html#generate-a-url). You have to use the `UrlGenerator` class then.

Comment: So i need to use config component. Thanks i will check more in docs

Comment: @Zend would you mind accepting an answer? I think my answer solves your initial question.